# Fixed columns and header with CSS/Angular JS

Tags: html, css, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am having trouble implementing the following:

> 1. Fix the header of the table
> 2. Fix first 4/5 columns to freeze and the rest to scroll horizontally
> 3. The table should be inside a div which is of fixed height and width

I am able to fix the header, I am not able to achieve #2. The table is inside a pane on the page. So I can't really use `position:absolute` to fix the columns to achieve #2.

I tried out few examples online to achieve this, but I need to create an angular JS directive to do this. I am new to AngularJS, however, I tried to tweak the below example but no luck.

https://www.pointblankdevelopment.com.au/blog/angularjs-fixed-header-scrollable-table-directive

Any help on a CSS way to do this also will help.

I also added the plunker for what I am trying to do. So I want to freeze first 2 columns in the example.

http://plnkr.co/edit/iKwNrqT1Gy1oDvyK6FFN?p=preview

Comment: It would be helpfull if you would set up a jsbin/jsfiddle/plunker with your attempts.

Comment: I tried to use multiple tables like http://jsfiddle.net/zS7Ny/ but i dont want to use 2 tables because the data is a single list which i need to iterate twice.

Comment: You want horizontal scroll applied only to `specific columns`?
Did you try this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21778035/967638) from jthe.

Comment: i tried this example, no luck. i have my table inside a div. the div is horizontaly scrollable. so the entire thing still scrolls to right.

Comment: i added the plunker to give an idea of what i already have. thanks !

Answer (score -2):

If you just add more rows to the `thead` it will automatically fix them for you as the directive calls to do.

See here: http://embed.plnkr.co/CmJBfd/preview

Thus, all you have to do is put a custom class on your rows that you do not want to look like the header and style them like the rows.

Comment: This does not have frozen columns like asked for